# Is it possible to how VSCode work of a global ESLint file compared to using a local .eslint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I have looked up 3 or 4 different posts all about global ESLint files, but for me none of them work. I can get the CLI commands to work. But what I am looking for is the live linting in VSCode as I work. It seems to only work if I create some kind of ESLint configuration in the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after running the CLI and finding a `--config` option where I listed the path for me `.eslintrc.json` file but for some reason I get a warning in VSCode saying config files are deprecated please use per project or `--config` which I just used...